# How to manually escape sensitive characters in a java string that will be run in a bash shell

Tags: java, regex, bash, escaping

I will receive use input in a java program as a string that will then be run on a bash shell to execute. My question is how to manually input a backslash in the string I am passing to the bash shell to escape sensitive characters?

I know that you need to change ; to \; to use the semicolon as a string inside the bash shell.

so for example what I want:
user input = "input;otherinput"
javaprogram -> sees the ; in the input and adds a \ to string to escape that once it is in bash shell
->output would be "input\;otherinput"

I have tried using methods like **String.replaceAll("\;", "\\\\;");** or **String.replaceAll(";", "\\\\;");**

I understand needing to double escape \\ in regex to get a backslash literal ( if I am interpreting it correctly ) basically is using replace or replaceAll methods capable of accomplishing what I am looking for? or do I need to do something else?

Additionally if have seen **org.apache.commons.text.StringEscapeUtils.escapeHtml4** for example which escapes automatically for html4 characters, But I am unsure if any of the other the other method versions (that escape things other than html4) would accomplish what I need in relation to bash shell escaping.

Any help is appreciated thank you.

Comment: Its not very clear why you need to escape semi-colon in bash.

Comment: I think we need to see some example input. What you *think* might need to be escaped might not be right

Comment: This would be example input of a password. the password will be wrapped in " passwordinput " but I have read that this does not prevent command injection guarenteed. so I was looking to manually escape special characters starting with semicolon so that the are interpreted as their literal instead of as their bash function

Comment: Note that password inputs should be taken in a way that they're not left in the terminal/logging. That said, if a user put in `if [ something]; then echo 3; else echo 4; fi`, I'd imagine they would want the proper bash output. You can instead rely on proper bash-shell usage instead of reinventing the bash parsing, so users wanting to pass `;` in string form would need to use quotes: `examplecmd some_input="abc;def;ghi"`. You can take the password as a separate prompt after the command (relaying the stdout if this is a terminal emulator).

Comment: Overall, my comment concerns that `;` is not the only character that has special meaning in bash, you're looking at `{`, `}`, `$`, `!`, `#`, `[`, `]`, `(`, `)`, `"` and more.

Comment: I suspect that you could solve your problem by using [ProcessBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) instead of Runtime.exec.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you simply want to replace ";" by "\;" (backslash semicolon) then just use `replace`, it does not need regex version `replaceAll`:

```
System.out.println("abc;def;ghi".replace(";", "\\;"))
// prints:
abc\;def\;ghi
```

Comment: This worked. I had simply not realized replace did not need regex as a parameter vs replaceAll and that avoided all of the weirdness I was encountering. Thank you